# Can i make the profile in android to silent or normal in a service class

Tags: android

Here i created a service to get the current location and when location changed i get the lat and lng and through geocoder i display the sub locality....
    is it possible to make the profile to silent if the user reaches a particular sublocality.
    I tried so but i am receiving a null pointer exception....
    can anybody help..i am new to android..

```
package com.secure.call_block;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Locale;

    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.location.Address;
    import android.location.Geocoder;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class MyService extends Service
    {
        Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "BOOMBOOMTESTGPS";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000*8;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener{
        Location mLastLocation;
        public LocationListener(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
            mLastLocation.set(location);

            /*----------to get City-Name from coordinates ------------- */
            String cityName=null;                 
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());                  
            List<Address>  addresses;  
            try {  
             addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);  
             if (addresses.size() > 0)  
              System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());  
             Address address = addresses.get(0);
             cityName= address.getSubLocality();
             System.out.println("CCCCCCCCCIIIIIIIIIIIIITTTTTTTTTTTYYYYYY "+cityName);
            } catch (IOException e) {                 
             e.printStackTrace();  
            } 

//i think i am having problem from here onwards....
            if(SetLocation.workcityName!=null)
            {
            if(SetLocation.workcityName.equalsIgnoreCase(cityName))
            {
                AudioManager audiomanager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                audiomanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
            }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);            
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    } 
    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);       
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        initializeLocationManager();
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }
    }






11-29 12:25:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18925): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 12:25:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18925): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-29 12:25:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18925):    at com.secure.call_block.MyService$LocationListener.onLocationChanged(MyService.java:57)
11-29 12:25:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18925):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:252)
11-29 12:25:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18925):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:185)
11-29 12:25:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18925):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:201)
11-29 12:25:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18925):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-29 12:25:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18925):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-29 12:25:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18925):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-29 12:25:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18925):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: @AnchitMittal: i have added my error msgs

Comment: should i need to give any permission in the manifest file ....

Comment: What all permissions you have provided.....

Post your manifest.

Comment: Thanks ......it worked  i changed the context...to BaseContext when getting audio service...and it worked :)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer just need to change the context to getBaseContext(),and the ringer will turn silent

AudioManager audiomanager = (AudioManager)  getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    audiomanager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);